# Global Vars Overwritten In C#

Tags: c#

I've set a bunch of static variables

```
public class globalvars
{
      /// <summary>
      /// Is user logged in
      /// </summary>
      public static string strUserName
      {
          get;
          set;
      }
}
```

And then used them throughout my project

```
public class logintowebsite : CustomerMappings
{


  public static void QuickLoginCheck()
   {
       try
       {
           LoginDetails user = ActiveSubsite.Instance.SubsiteSettings.CurrentUser;
           globalvars.strUserName = "Bert";

       }
       catch
       {
           globalvars.strUserName = "Ernie";
       }

}
```

trouble is, when two users are using the page at the same time the first users' details get overwritten by the second because they're replaced in .

Any ideas why this might be occurring.

Answer (score 6):

> when two users are using the page at the same time the first users' details get overwritten by the second because they're replaced in .
>   Any ideas why this might be occurring.

Yes, because they are `static`.

Don't use static variables in ASP.NET(i assume) when you don't want to share them between all requests since every request is a different thread.

You could use the [`Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried Session but doesn't always hold the variables on all devices.

Answer (score 2):

this is a case of [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), you must use session variable/cookies/other caching pattern to make it unique for each user

Comment: i endorse the use of the singleton pattern.

Answer (score 1):

`strUserName` is static. Meaning there is only one `strUserName` for all  `globalvars`

By declaring something `static` you can call something like `SomeClass.SomeStaticVarName` - no instance of `SomeClass` has to be created to get to `SomeStaticVarName`

When I was in school I struggled with the concept of static, let me know if you want a better example.